# Pronoun difference in translation for this sentence

Tags: translation

서로 같이 있으면 감정만 더 상할 것 같아
Google translate, translates this to "I think our feelings will only get hurt more if we stay together."

Given that pronouns in Korean can be context specific, can this be actually translated as "I think YOUR feelings will only get hurt more if we stay together."

By itself, "감정만 더 상할" could mean "It will hurt your feelings more". Since there is a mention of 서로 같이 있으면 Google translates this to "our feelings". But depending on the context it could also mean "your feelings" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's pretty unlikely.  The sentence contains 서로 (each other), which is normally used for a situation where something happens in both directions, e.g., A hurts B's feeling and vice versa.  E.g.,

- 서로 사랑하라.  Love each other.
- 서로 비난하는 모습이 안타깝구나.  It's regrettable that [you guys] are blaming each other.
- 다른 전하끼리는 서로 끌어당긴다.  Opposite electric charges attract each other.

So, IMHO, the only natural interpretation of the sentence in question is "we will hurt each other's feelings."